# where condition to be a specific excel sheet range

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I an excel sql access query, it concatenates some fields and then narrows down the data set with a where clause. I have many where clauses, I am wondering if its possible to declare a sheet name with header/range as my where clause instead of having a list of +100 where strings.

My query is,

```
select b.*
from (Select B.*, B.[RF attribute1] & "|" & B.[RF attribute2] & "|" & B.[RF attribute3] & "|" & B.[RF attribute4] as new_field 
      from [BlackMonday1987$] as B 
     ) as b
where new_field in ('a','b','c')
```

But how do I do something like, where this clause will use all fields within header1 on sheet 1. I have tried the below, not sure if it can be done or if its the right logic.

```
where new_field = [Sheet1$].[header1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The IN clause cannot be dynamic. It must be fixed values.

You can create the full SQL from code, but that's it.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will ask this, is there any limitation to how much where clause words I can include in an excel sql access query?

Comment: Yes, though it is quite high. If in doubt, write the values to a (temp) table and include this in the query.

Comment: How can I put values into a temp table? Can I do this without vba?

Comment: Yes, an append or create-table query can do it.